# simple-private-messages gem keep saying it has error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I acesss http://example.com/users/1/messages/new   it says

```
undefined method `error_message_on' for #<#<Class:0x00000005921d50>:0x0000000591e448>
```

If I delete the lines that have "error_message_on" from view,
no error appears but it shows blank page. so weird :(

messages new view is just like this. whats wrong?
Thanks in advance!!

```
<% form_for @message, :url => user_messages_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <p>
    To:<br />
        <%= f.text_field :to %>
        <%= error_message_on @message, :to %>
  </p>
  <p>
    Subject:<br />
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
    <%= error_message_on @message, :subject %>
    </p>
    <p>
      Message<br />
      <%= f.text_area :body %>
            <%= error_message_on @message, :body %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the erb tags you are using for the form_for declaration. It should be `<%=` instead of `<%`. That should fix the blank page.

As far as how to display the error messages, `error_message_on` was [deprecated in Rails 2.3.8](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper/error_message_on). You'll need to use something that is supported in your version of Rails. [This question might be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803180/rails-3-how-to-display-error-messages-in-embedded-form) and there's also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873190/f-error-messages-in-rails-3-0)

Comment: Thanks for beautiful answer, this gem says "It's rails3 compatible" so that I just followed the direction what it says here https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages  but it was not compatible. was it?